# Updating Parse Cloud Code on self hosted Parse-Server on compute engine

Tags: node.js, parse-platform, google-compute-engine, parse-server

I have successfully deployed a self hosted Parse Server on Google Compute Engine.
I will further need to develop and change my cloud code (main.js)

**Is there any way to only update the changes on this file instead of doing new deployment?**

Comment: Do you mean updating cloud code while parse-server is running ?

Answer (score 0):

No, changes need to be deployed to GCE to become effective.

If deployment takes too long for testing you can set up a local parse server where you can change the cloud code files on the fly while parse server is running and any changes become effective immediately.